# Installing NPM packages in angular 6 workspace

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli-v6

I am just picking up Angular 6 and CLI and have created a project as below

```
ng new my-demo
cd my-demo
ng g library foo --prefix=my
```

No in my library I want to add `ngx-bootstrap` as the component will need the `DropdownButtonModule` so my question is how do I go about installing the npm package for the library?

I would previously have just run `npm install ngx-bootstrap` but this will now install the package for the application, however, I need this installed for the library.  Should I be cd'ing to the library folder and running npm install or is there an alternate way this is n ow done using the CLI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can continue to use `npm install packagename`.

The package.json is not attached to a specific application or library within your workspace, but to your complete angular/cli project. The build process (using webpack in the backend) will figure out which dependencies are actually necessary for your respective active build and drop the rest.

Comment: So when publishing the library, ng will know which packages are required and bundle them up within the list folder or does it not work that way?

Comment: Exactly, you can confirm this by installing a package but not adding it to your library. Then compare the pre- and post-install bundle sizes.

Comment: This took me ages to find this answer, thanks for clarifying. No tutorials I found mentioned this, I think it's pretty natural to incorrectly assume you put the packages into the package.json for the library you're creating!

Comment: *Correction*: You DO need to put dependencies into both package.json files. You only need to run `npm install` at the root level however.

Comment: Why then do libraries have a package.json if it's meaningless?

Comment: I suppose it's because package.json is not only for dependencies, but also for publishing. So each project in a workspace can have its own package.json having different name, version, authors, ...