# Install NPM package for angular library

Tags: angular, npm-install, npm-publish

I am just picking up Angular 8 and CLI and have created a project as below

```
ng new my-demo
cd my-demo
ng g library foo --prefix=my
```

Now in my library I want to add ngx-bootstrap as the component and will need the DropdownButtonModule so my question is how do I go about installing the npm package for the library?

I tried as suggested in the link [Installing NPM packages in angular 6 workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232682/installing-npm-packages-in-angular-6-workspace)

But build is failing and unable to identify the DropdownButtonModule in mylibrarymodule.ts file to import the module

Also i need to bundle the dependencies for the library

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First Install ngx-bootstrap from npm

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

Add BsDropdownModule to NgModule imports:

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),...]
  ...
})
```

Use it in your HTML file as below.

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In this snippet it doesn't show the complete way to handle this case, its not known if you are installing the package in library or in the project itself, and if you install it in library i dont remember it was with just simple `npm i 'name-of-package'`, you need to specify in which library you are installing it or if you installed it in library you accessed it with something like this maybe `../path/path`. More info would be better, i dont know how it marked as done